# How to use AngularSplitModule in angular9?

Tags: angular, angular9

I am trying to use the AngularSplitModule in my Angular9 project.

I am loading it as:

```
imports[
AngularSplitModule.forRoot()]
```

And in the html file, I am trying to use:

```
<split>
<split-area>
<Component1>
</split-area>
<split-area>
<Component2>
</split-area>

</split>
```

However I am getting this error:

```
error NG8001: 'split' is not a known element
```

Same for the split area...

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you check the import path of AngularSplitModule in appModule?

2) You may run npm install once.

3) Restart your code editor.

Comment: issue fixed..was using it in a child component.so had to import AngularSplitModule.forChild().After that the tags were <as-split>  and <as-split-area>.